# WooCommerce - change child category URL structure

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Let's say I have category **Foods** and it has a child: **Chicken**.

By default, the URL for Chicken category will be like: `yoursite.com/product-category/foods/chicken`.

Is there a way to make it `yoursite.com/product-category/chicken`? I want to keep the parent-child relation so I can query all Foods and list all child-categories of Foods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in your functions.php:

```
function ran_remove_parent_category_from_url( $args ) {
    $args['rewrite']['hierarchical'] = false;
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_taxonomy_args_product_cat', 'ran_remove_parent_category_from_url' );
```

Comment: Nice didn't expect the solution to be this simple. Thanks